# How to install mongodb on linux?

Tags: linux, installation, amazon-ec2

I'm a nuby on linux (never used it before), and I want to install mongodb on an EC2 linux instance.

I still haven't found a good article which guide how to install mongodb on an EC2 linux instance, 
which the data files are stored in an attached EBS.

Anyone know a good guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out some of these links, hopefully they should point you in the right direction:

- [Installing the MongoDB package on Ubuntu and Debian](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages)
- [Running MongoDB on EC2](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Amazon+EC2)
- [MongoDB EC2 Webinar](http://www.10gen.com/events/ec2)

Comment: Okay, here's the things I've done:
 (1) Attach the EBS volume to the instance, and mount it: http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/mounting.htm
 (2) Set auto mount on boot (/env/fstab): http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html
 (3) Install Mongo: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Amazon+EC2

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, this one worked out for me:

[How to set up PHP and MongoDB development environment in Ubuntu 12.04](http://quadloops.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-php-and-mongodb-development-environment-in-ubuntu-12-04/)